# Microsoft OS 2.0 USB descriptor - Composite Device - WINUSB

Tags: usb, driver

I'm trying to get a dual interface composite USB full speed device to associate the WINUSB driver with the device.  I'm attempting to use MS OS 2.0 descriptors to do this, but it seems with my descriptors, the WINUSB driver isn't being associated with my device.  My goal is to have the composite device show up as a single device in device manager with WINUSB as the driver.

I'm using a Windows 10 Host.  The spec I'm using for the descriptors is the "Microsoft OS 2.0 Descriptors Specification dated July 2018.

I have a few questions:

#1. What am I missing in this example I'm working from?  I thought this would associate WINUSB with my composite device - see full descriptors below (BOS + MS OS 2.0 descriptor set).  I believe I'm still seeing  my HID interface (interface 0) enumeration successfully and independently of interface 1 which is a bulk interface.

```
// BOS descriptor with platform capability descriptor

UCHAR platform_capability_descriptor[] = {
// BOS descriptor

0x05,       // Descriptor size (5 bytes)
0x0F,           // Descriptor type (BOS)
0x21, 0x00,     // Length of this + subordinate descriptors     
        // (33 bytes)
0x01,       // Number of subordinate descriptors

// Microsoft OS 2.0 Platform Capability Descriptor

0x1C,                   // Descriptor size (28 bytes)
0x10,                   // Descriptor type (Device Capability)
0x05,                   // Capability type (Platform)
0x00,                   // Reserved

// MS OS 2.0 Platform Capability ID (D8DD60DF-4589-4CC7-9CD2-659D9E648A9F)

0xDF, 0x60, 0xDD, 0xD8, 
0x89, 0x45,
0xC7, 0x4C,
0x9C, 0xD2, 
0x65, 0x9D, 0x9E, 0x64, 0x8A, 0x9F,

0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x06,     // Windows version (8.1) (0x06030000)
0x9E, 0x00,             // Size, MS OS 2.0 descriptor set (158 bytes)
0x01,               // Vendor-assigned bMS_VendorCode
0x00                // Doesn’t support alternate enumeration
}

// Microsoft OS 2.0 Descriptor Set

UCHAR ms_os_20_descriptor_set[] = {

0x0A, 0x00,                 // Descriptor size (10 bytes)
0x00, 0x00,                 // MS OS 2.0 descriptor set header
0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x06,             // Windows version (8.1) (0x06030000)
0x9E, 0x00,                 // Size, MS OS 2.0 descriptor set (158 bytes)

// Microsoft OS 2.0 compatible ID descriptor

0x14, 0x00,                     // Descriptor size (20 bytes)
0x03, 0x00,                         // MS OS 2.0 compatible ID descriptor
0x57, 0x49, 0x4E, 0x55, 0x53, 0x42, 0x00, 0x00,     // WINUSB string
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,     // Sub-compatible ID

// Registry property descriptor

0x80, 0x00,             // Descriptor size (128 bytes)
0x04, 0x00,             // Registry Property descriptor
0x01, 0x00,             // Strings are null-terminated Unicode
0x28, 0x00,             // Size of Property Name (40 bytes)

//Property Name ("DeviceInterfaceGUID")

0x44, 0x00, 0x65, 0x00, 0x76, 0x00, 0x69, 0x00, 0x63, 0x00, 0x65, 0x00,
0x49, 0x00, 0x6E, 0x00, 0x74, 0x00, 0x65, 0x00, 0x72, 0x00, 0x66, 0x00,
0x61, 0x00, 0x63, 0x00, 0x65, 0x00, 0x47, 0x00, 0x55, 0x00, 0x49, 0x00,
0x44, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 

0x4E, 0x00,             // Size of Property Data (78 bytes)

// Vendor-defined Property Data: {ecceff35-146c-4ff3-acd9-8f992d09acdd}

0x7B, 0x00, 0x65, 0x00, 0x63, 0x00, 0x63, 0x00, 0x65, 0x00, 0x66, 0x00,
0x66, 0x00, 0x33, 0x00, 0x35, 0x00, 0x2D, 0x00, 0x31, 0x00, 0x34, 0x00,
0x36, 0x00, 0x33, 0x00, 0x2D, 0x00, 0x34, 0x00, 0x66, 0x00, 0x66, 0x00,
0x33, 0x00, 0x2D, 0x00, 0x61, 0x00, 0x63, 0x00, 0x64, 0x00, 0x39, 0x00,
0x2D, 0x00, 0x38, 0x00, 0x66, 0x00, 0x39, 0x00, 0x39, 0x00, 0x32, 0x00,
0x64, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x39, 0x00, 0x61, 0x00, 0x63, 0x00, 0x64, 0x00,
0x64, 0x00, 0x7D, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
}
```

With this approach it looks like one interface (HID - Interface 0) shows up fine and the bulk interface (interface 2) doesn't get a driver. So with this it looks like usbccgp.sys is still being associated.

#2. Do you need the uuid and "DeviceInterfaceGUI" info or can you use a simpler descriptor shown below.  The spec seems to state you can do this.  Would the below work without the DeviceInterface GUID info?

```
// BOS descriptor with platform capability descriptor

UCHAR platform_capability_descriptor[] = {
// BOS descriptor

0x05,       // Descriptor size (5 bytes)
0x0F,           // Descriptor type (BOS)
0x21, 0x00,     // Length of this + subordinate descriptors     
        // (33 bytes)
0x01,       // Number of subordinate descriptors

// Microsoft OS 2.0 Platform Capability Descriptor

0x1C,                   // Descriptor size (28 bytes)
0x10,                   // Descriptor type (Device Capability)
0x05,                   // Capability type (Platform)
0x00,                   // Reserved

// MS OS 2.0 Platform Capability ID (D8DD60DF-4589-4CC7-9CD2-659D9E648A9F)

0xDF, 0x60, 0xDD, 0xD8, 
0x89, 0x45,
0xC7, 0x4C,
0x9C, 0xD2, 
0x65, 0x9D, 0x9E, 0x64, 0x8A, 0x9F,

0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x06,     // Windows version (8.1) (0x06030000)
0x1E, 0x00,             // Size, MS OS 2.0 descriptor set (158 bytes)
0x01,               // Vendor-assigned bMS_VendorCode
0x00                // Doesn’t support alternate enumeration
}

// Microsoft OS 2.0 Descriptor Set

UCHAR ms_os_20_descriptor_set[] = {

0x0A, 0x00,                 // Descriptor size (10 bytes)
0x00, 0x00,                 // MS OS 2.0 descriptor set header
0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x06,             // Windows version (8.1) (0x06030000)
0x1E, 0x00,                 // Size, MS OS 2.0 descriptor set (158 bytes)

// Microsoft OS 2.0 compatible ID descriptor

0x14, 0x00,                     // Descriptor size (20 bytes)
0x03, 0x00,                         // MS OS 2.0 compatible ID descriptor
0x57, 0x49, 0x4E, 0x55, 0x53, 0x42, 0x00, 0x00,     // WINUSB string
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,     // Sub-compatible ID
}
```

#3 Why are the bytes of part of the UUID shown below LSB first, but then towards the end the byte order is swapped MSB first?  This seems to be required as my testing shows without this byte order (that seems to change) the enumeration fails completely.

```
// MS OS 2.0 Platform Capability ID (D8DD60DF-4589-4CC7-9CD2-659D9E648A9F)
0xDF, 0x60, 0xDD, 0xD8, // this makes sense
0x89, 0x45,
0xC7, 0x4C,
0x9C, 0xD2, // this seems to be backwards
0x65, 0x9D, 0x9E, 0x64, 0x8A, 0x9F,// this seems to be backwards
```

You can see here that LSB byte is first for "D8DD60DF", but for "659D9E648A9F" MSB comes first when looking at the byte order.

#4 As a sanity check, is it correct to provide only the BOS descriptor info and the "Microsoft OS 2.0 Descriptor Set Header" and a single feature descriptor for the whole device?  In my case this feature descriptor would be the "Microsoft OS 2.0 Compatible ID descriptor".  I don't need the configuration descriptors and the spec seems to say you don't have to supply them.

I thought I could just use the BOS and MS OS 2.0 descriptor set data that stopped after the compatible ID for WINUSB to get my usb composite device to show up with WINUSB driver for the entire device.

Thanks for any help / advice!

Answer (score 1):

#1: You have a composite device so you need to use the "configuration subset" and "function subset header" structures defined by Microsoft in your Microsoft OS 2.0 Descriptor Set.  Here is a working, open-source example showing how to get WinUSB automatically loaded for an interface on a composite device:

https://github.com/pololu/libusbp/blob/b4666d1/test/firmware/wixel/main.c

Note that the configuration number you use in the "configuration subset" is actually a zero-based index instead of the usual configuration number from the USB specification; Microsoft's spec is unclear about that.

#2: You do need the device interface GUID; that is a fundamental part of how you actually open a handle to the WinUSB device.  You should generate your own GUID with a utility like uuidgen.  Don't just use some random GUID from the Internet which might have a special meaning to third-party software.

#3: I don't know much about UUID byte order, but I glanced at this [this blog post](http://howtowriteaprogram.blogspot.com/2009/03/uuid-and-byte-order.html) and it seems like Microsoft was using the "little-endian, as described in SMBIOS V2.6".  It really doesn't matter though, just copy the bytes shown in the examples in the order they are shown.

#4: Besides the standard USB descriptors, which include a configuration descriptor, the only two blocks of descriptors you need are the BOS descriptor and the Microsoft OS 2.0 Descriptor Set.

#5: I recommend using C character literals where appropriate to make your descriptors more readable.  For example, the first byte of WINSUB should be written as `'W'`.

#6: Don't forget to set bcdUSB to 0x201 or later in your device descriptor.

#7: You might want to change your product ID or serial after making descriptor changes just to force Windows to really request the descriptors and not rely on caches.

Comment: Hi David, Thank you very much for the reply!  I really appreciate it. I'm actually trying to get my composite device to associate WINUSB with the entire device rather than an interface.  I apologize I wasn't clear and you are correct for interfaces.  My issue is an attempt to get the whole composite device to show up as a single WINUSB device.  That's why I *thought* I didn't need the configuration and function descriptors.  Do you know if that is correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's right.  The example I linked you to shows the Micrsoft OS 2.0 Descriptor Set for a non-composite device on line 430, and it doesn't have those in it.  If your problem is that Windows is selecting the composite parent driver instead of WinUSB, you might need to change part of your device's device descriptor (like the class code) so that it doesn't get recognized as a composite device.  But then it's weird that you would have multiple interfaces: if you're letting WinUSB claim the whole device you could just have one interface.